# SQL Identify a specific CharIndex then work backwards to get a previous section of the string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, reporting-services

We have a change log that unfortunately concatenates all changes into one long string.

i.e.

```
username1 xx:xx:xx
start -> mm/dd/yy
approved no -> yes

username2 xx:xx:xx
firm no -> yes
reqby mm/dd/yy -> mm/dd/yy
target -> mm/dd/yy

etc...
```

I need to skip down through the string until I find the '**target**' change then step back to find the username associated with that change.  So in the above instance I'd find 'target' then look back and see it was made by username2.

The problem is that any number of changes could be made before the we find the index where the '**target**' change is.  If I could step backward like a reverse loop I could just look for the first instance of the time stamp '%:*:*:%'.

Is there way to do a reverse loop in SQL using a case statement?  Or could you need to do a stored procedure?

Example:

```
daviejo  16:57:39 New Record.

daviejo  17:00:07
 Req. By: 02/12/15 -> 02/17/15
Released: n -> y

scottwi  17:00:19
 Target:  -> 02/12/15

daviejo  17:00:07
 Req. By: 02/17/15 -> 03/17/15

daviejo  17:00:07
 Req. By: 03/17/15 -> 03/30/15

scottwi  13:00:15
 Target:  02/12/15 -> 03/25/15
```

I would want to see a record for scottwi twice.  I can parse out the date and such.  This would be grouped in an ssrs report by username with details per change.

Comment: O lord I feel sorry for you...I cannot understand why developers do stuff like this!

Comment: What pattern/logic identifies a username as a username? Can there be multiple `target` tokens?

Comment: Username consists of first 5 of last name + first 2 of first name...ex. Mike Johnson would be johnsmi.  Targets can show up multiple times through the log and multiple times per user change.

Comment: Do you need to return the username for every instance of "target"?

Comment: Oh I see what you meant.  Yes if the events are separate timestamps I want to capture how many times they have changed the target field.

Comment: Perhaps an example with what you're actually looking for would help. Actual values with expected results, etc.

Comment: Hi Fstagger,thx for your accept! Please allow me one hint: I visited your profile and found, that within several years you've placed not more than one single up vote. All professionals giving answers on SO are hungry for reputation points. If you like my answer (and I personally think this is one of my most creative :-Q) I would appreciate if you'd accept AND upvote this. And please start to be very generous with your votes, 'cause this is how SO is working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One tricky approach - very much depending on the line-feed-characters you are using! - would be this:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(MAX)=
'username1 xx:xx:xx
start -> mm/dd/yy
approved no -> yes

username2 xx:xx:xx
firm no -> yes
reqby mm/dd/yy -> mm/dd/yy
target -> mm/dd/yy

username5 xx:xx:xx
firm no -> yes
reqby mm/dd/yy -> mm/dd/yy
target -> mm/dd/yy';

DECLARE @AsXml XML=
(
SELECT CAST('<block><item>' 
       + REPLACE
         (
           REPLACE(
                   @s
                  ,CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
                  ,'</item></block><block><item>'
                  )
            ,CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
            ,'</item><item>'
          ) 
       + '</item></block>' AS XML)
);
```

The result

```
<block>
  <item>username1 xx:xx:xx</item>
  <item>start -&gt; mm/dd/yy</item>
  <item>approved no -&gt; yes</item>
</block>
<block>
  <item>username2 xx:xx:xx</item>
  <item>firm no -&gt; yes</item>
  <item>reqby mm/dd/yy -&gt; mm/dd/yy</item>
  <item>target -&gt; mm/dd/yy</item>
</block>
<block>
  <item>username5 xx:xx:xx</item>
  <item>firm no -&gt; yes</item>
  <item>reqby mm/dd/yy -&gt; mm/dd/yy</item>
  <item>target -&gt; mm/dd/yy</item>
</block>
```

You query the XML like this

```
SELECT Item.value('.','varchar(max)') AS item
      ,Item.value('../item[1]','varchar(max)') AS RelatedUser
FROM @AsXml.nodes('/block/item') AS One(Item)
WHERE Item.value('.','varchar(max)') LIKE 'target%'
```

And you get

```
item                RelatedUser
target -> mm/dd/yy  username2 xx:xx:xx
target -> mm/dd/yy  username5 xx:xx:xx
```

Tested with your sample data from your edit. With this you get (be aware of the space before "Target"!)

```
item                              RelatedUser
Target:  -> 02/12/15              scottwi  17:00:19
Target:  02/12/15 -> 03/25/15     scottwi  13:00:15
```

Comment: @TT, Thx! I **love** these XML-hacks... XPath-Navigation allows here to say: Yeah, we found an item which starts with "target", go one level up and then pick the first item-element which is the related user.